# Выбор одного из значений (из select или из input) при отправке формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В форме нужен `select` с некими значениями, последнее из которых - *"Другое"*. При выборе этого значения появляется поле `input`, в которое можно вписать своё значение.

При отправке всё должно сохраняться в базу. Значит, значение из `select` и из `input` должны писаться в одно и то же поле базы. При выборе в `select` *"Другое"* должно писаться значение из `input`.

Как отправить на сервер только нужное значение?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вопрос только при клиентскую часть? Про то, как отобразить элемент и правильно сформировать запрос?

Comment: да, jquery есть. Нужно да, отобразить клиентскую часть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея такова:

- При изменении значения в `select` показываем или скрываем `input`.
- `input` при загрузке страницы скрыт.
- При отправке формы запрещаем стандартную отправку и отсылаем с помощью Ajax-запроса.
- В качестве параметра `value` при запросе указывает либо значение `select`, либо значение `input`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $select = $('#select');
    var $custom = $('#custom');
    var customValue = 'Другое';
    
    $('#form').on('submit', function() {
        var value = $select.val();
        if (value == customValue) {
            value = $custom.val();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'send.php',
            data: { 'value': value }
        });
        return false;
    });
    
    $select.on('change', function() {
        $custom.toggle($(this).val() == customValue);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
#custom {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="">
    <select id="select">
        <option>First</option>
        <option>Second</option>
        <option>Другое</option>
    </select>
    <input id="custom" placeholder="Введите своё значение" />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вариант со стандартной отправкой формы:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $select = $('#select');
    var $custom = $('#custom');
    var customValue = 'Другое';
    
    $('#form').on('submit', function() {
        var $element = $select;
        if ($select.val() == customValue) {
            $element = $custom;
        }
        $element.attr('name', 'value');
    });
    
    $select.on('change', function() {
        $custom.toggle($(this).val() == customValue);
    });
});
```

```css
#custom {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="index.php">
    <select id="select">
        <option>First</option>
        <option>Second</option>
        <option>Другое</option>
    </select>
    <input id="custom" placeholder="Введите своё значение" />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qce13mju/).

Comment: Так то он так. Но у меня вся отправка идет через компонент сайта. Сайт на ModX. Поэтому запрещать что-либо не хотелось бы. А без этого никак, да?

Comment: @Batyabest первый момент - в вопросе не было ни слова про компоненты, библиотеки и прочие страшные штуки, которые умеют усложнять всем жизнь. Поэтому я спокойно написал код для чистой страницы. Второй момент - а в чем именно проблема с запретом стандартной отправки формы?

Comment: Проблема с запретом стандартной отправки в том, что все работает и не надо ничего запрещать, нужно лишь реализовать появление блока инпут при выборе в селекте "Другое" или как вариант сдделать так, чтобы при не пустом значении из этого инпут оно писалось в бд, иначе - значение из селекта.

Comment: @Batyabest это получится костыльно-ориентированное решение: перед отправкой формы удалять `select`, если в `input` есть значение. В противное случае - удалять `input`. Звучит не очень здорово.

Comment: Да что же поделать пусть будет костыльное.

Comment: @Batyabest добавил вариант со стандартной отправкой формы в ответ.